# Repdigit Base Finding

Tags: code-golf, base-conversion

A [repdigit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repdigit) is a natural number that can be written solely by repeating the same digit. For example, `777` is a repdigit, since it's solely composed of the digit `7` repeated three times.

This isn't limited to simply decimal (base 10) numbers, however:

- Every Mersenne number (of the form *M<sub>n</sub> = 2<sup>n</sup>-1*) is a repdigit when written in binary (base 2).
- Every number is trivially a repdigit when written in unary (base 1).
- Every number `n` can also trivially be written as the repdigit `11` in base `n-1` (for example, `17` when written in hexadecimal (base 16) is `11`, and `3` when written in binary (base 2) is also `11`).

The challenge here is to find *other* bases where the input number may be a repdigit.

#### Input

A positive integer `x > 3`, in any convenient format.

#### Output

A positive integer `b` with `(x-1) > b > 1` where the representation of `x` in base `b` is a repdigit.

- If no such `b` exists, output `0` or some [falsey](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2194/42963) value.
- If multiple such `b` exist, you can output any or all of them.

#### Rules

- The `(x-1) > b > 1` restriction is to prevent the trivial conversions to unary or the "subtract one" base. The *output* number can be written in unary or any convenient base, but the *base itself* must not be one of the trivial conversions.
- Input/output can be via any [suitable method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- [Standard loophole](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) restrictions apply.

#### Examples

```
In --> Out
11 --> 0            (or other falsey value)
23 --> 0            (or other falsey value)
55 --> 10           (since 55 is 55 in base 10)
90 --> 14           (since 90 is 66 in base 14 ... 17, 29, 44 also allowed)
91 --> 9            (since 91 is 111 in base 9 ... 12 also allowed)
```

Comment: Can we assume `b ≤ 36` (many languages' built-in base conversion functions don't go higher)?

Comment: @Doorknob Assuming `b ≤ 36` *severely* limits the scope of this problem, and all of the existing answers correctly handle larger bases, so I'm going to say no, you cannot assume an upper bound on `b` beyond what's given.

Comment: Most numbers are repdigits in some base. For instance, 91 = 13 * 7 so it's 77 in base 12.

Comment: @Neil ... It's almost like you're on to something, there ...

Answer (score 11):

## Jelly, <s>11</s> 9 bytes

```
bRI¬P€TḊṖ
```

Returns a list of bases, which is empty (falsy) if there is none. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=YlJJwqxQ4oKsVOG4iuG5lg&input=&args=OTA)

#### How it works

```
bRI¬P€TḊṖ  Main link. Argument: x (number)

 R         Range; yield [1, ..., x].
b          Base; convert x to base n, for each n in the range.
  I        Compute the increment (differences of successive values) of each array
           of base-n digits. This yields only 0's for a repdigit.
   ¬       Apply logical NOT to each increment.
    P€     Compute the product of all lists of increments.
      T    Get the indices of all truthy products.
       Ḋ   Discard the first index (1).
        Ṗ  Discard the last index (x - 1).
```

Answer (score 9):

## Pyth, <del>11</del> 10

```
fqjQT)r2tQ
```

Apparently Pyth's unary `q` checks for a list that has all unique values as of about 10 days ago. Apparently investigating Pyth bugs improves golf scores.

Filters the list `[2..input-1)` on if the unique set of digits of the input in that base is length 1.

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=fqjQT%29r2tQ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=11%0A23%0A55%0A90%0A91&debug=0)

#### Explanation:

```
r2tQ     ##  generate the python range from 2 to the input (Q) - 1
         ##  python range meaning inclusive lower and exclusive upper bounds
f        ##  filter that list with lambda T:
  jQT    ##  convert the input to base T
 q    )  ##  true if the resulting list digits has all equal elements
```

Answer (score 5):

### Ruby, <s>87</s> <s>69</s> 63 bytes

```ruby
->x{(2..x-2).find{|b|y=x;a=y%b;a=0if a!=y%b while(y/=b)>0;a>0}}
```

I had to implement base conversion by hand, since Ruby's builtins only go up to base 36...

Returns `nil` for not found.

```ruby
->x{      # anonymous lambda that takes one argument
(2..x-2)  # range of the possible bases to search over
.find{    # return the first element that satisfies the block, or nil if none
|b|       # b represents the base currently being tested
y=x;      # a temporary value to avoid mutating the original value of x
a=y%b;    # the first (well, last) digit in base b, which will be compared to

                   y/=b      # divide the number by the base
   if a!=y%b                 # if this digit does not match (is different)...
a=0                          # set a to a value representing "failure"
             while(    )>0;  # keep doing this until we get zero (no digits left)

a>0       # return whether a has maintained its original value (no digit change)
}}        # find then returns the first element for which this is true (or nil)
```

Answer (score 5):

### Python, 71 <strike>72</strike> <strike>78</strike> bytes

```python
lambda x:{b for b in range(2,x-1)for d in range(x)if x*~-b==x%b*~-b**d}
```

No recursion, just tries all bases and outputs a set of those that work.

It's tempting to encode `b` and `d` in a single number, but it takes too many parenthesized expressions to extract them. 77 bytes:

```python
lambda x:{k/x for k in range(2*x,x*x-x))if x*~-(k/x)==x%(k/x)*~-(k/x)**(k%x)}
```

---

**72 bytes:**

```python
f=lambda x,b=2:b*any(x*~-b==x%b*~-b**d for d in range(x))or f(x,b+1)%~-x
```

Outputs the first `b` that works, or `0` if none do.

A rep-unit `x` of `d` digits of `c` in base `b` has value `x==c*(b**d-1)/(b-1)`. Equivalently, `x*(b-1)==c*(b**d-1)`.

The value `c` must be `x%b`, the last digit. I don't see a way though to determine `d` arithmetically, so the code tries all possibilities to see if any of them work.

Saved 5 bytes by copying [Dennis's trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/75664/20260) of giving a falsey output when `b` reaches `x-1` by taking the output modulo `x-1`. Another byte saved from Dennis reminding me that exponentiation inexplicably has higher precedence that `~`.

An equal-length solution with `in` instead of `any`.

```python
f=lambda x,b=2:b*(x*~-b in[x%b*~-b**d for d in range(x)])or f(x,b+1)%~-x
```

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 50 bytes

```
->n{(2..n-2).find{|b,i=n|i%b==(i/=b)%b ?redo:i<1}}
```

I would really like to remove that annoying space but as a newcomer to ruby, I'm still quite unfamiliar with its syntactic quirks.

Comment: The offending quirk in this case is that `b?` would be a valid method name, so you can’t get rid of the space.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 79 bytes

```
f=lambda x,b=2:~-b*x in[i%b*~-b**(i/b)for i in range(b*x)]and b or f(x,-~b)%~-x
```

Try it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/1GgtGC).

#### Idea

Any repdigit **x** of base **b > 1** and digit **d < b** satisfies the following.

[image: condition]

Since **d < b**, the map **(b, d) ↦ cb + d** is injective.

Also, since **b, x > 1**, we have **c < x**, so **cb + d < cb + b = (c + 1)b ≤ xb**.

This means that, to find suitable values for **c** and **d** for a given base **b**, we can iterate through all **i** in **[0, …, bx)** and check whether **(b - 1)x == (i % b)(b<sup>i / b</sup> - 1)**.

#### Code

The named lambda **f** test whether **(b - 1)x** is in the set **{(i % b)(b<sup>i / b</sup> - 1) | 0 ≤ i < bx}**, beginning with the value **b = 2**.

- If the test was successful, we return **b**.
- Else, we call **f** again, with the same **x** and **b** incremented by **1**.

Since **b** may eventually reach **x - 1**, we take the final result modulo **x - 1** to return **0** in this case. Note that this will not happen if **b = 2** satisfies the condition, since it is returned without recursing. However, the question guarantees that **b = 2 < x - 1** in this case.

Answer (score 4):

## [Emojicode](http://www.emojicode.org/), 214 bytes

(77 characters):

```
➡bi 2n 0◀i➖b 1vb i▶vv 0 1vn iin 90
```

Prints results in base 9.

I've been meaning to do a code golf with emojicode for a couple weeks now, but the language has only recently become stable enough to actually work with . As a bonus, this question makes use of the one piece of functionality emojicode is actually really good at: representing integers in other bases.

Ungolfed ( is a line comment in emojicode)

```
          define main class ""
  ➡   define main method

     read an integer from stdin, store it in frozen variable "b"
     b     

     i 2   i = 2
     n 0   n = 0

    ◀i➖b 1      while i < b - 1
       v b i   v = the string representation of b in base i

       Split v on every instance of the first character of v.
       If the length of that list is greater than the actual length of v,
       n = i
      ▶vv 0 1v
         n i
      

       i   increment i
    
      n 9   represent n in base 9 instead of 10, to save a byte 
     0           return error code 0
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 28 bytes

```
 {b/⍨⍵{1=≢∪⍵⊥⍣¯1⊢⍺}¨b←1+⍳⍵-3}
```

`{`…`⍵`…`}` anonymous function to be applied to `x` (represented by `⍵`)
`b←1+⍳⍵-3` integers from 2 – ⍵-2 stored as `b`
`⍵{`…`}¨` for each element in b (`⍵`), apply the function `{`…`}` with x as left argument `⍺`
`⍵⊥⍣¯1⊢⍺` convert x to that base
`1=≢∪` is 1 equal to the tally of unique digit?
`b/⍨` elements of b where true (that there is only one unique digit).

[Example cases](http://tryapl.org/?a=%7Bb/%u2368%u2375%7B1%3D%u2262%u222A%u2375%u22A5%u2363%AF1%u22A2%u237A%7D%A8b%u21901+%u2373%u2375-3%7D%A811%2023%2055%2090%2091&run)

If no base exists, the output is empty (which is falsey), as can be demonstrated by this program:

```
 WhatIsEmpty
 →''/TRUE ⍝ goto (→) TRUE: if (/) emptystring ('')
 'False'
 →END       
TRUE:       
 'True'     
END:
```

This prints 'False'

Answer (score 3):

## Perl 6, <s>45</s> <s>43</s> 42 bytes

```perl6
{grep 2..$^x-2: {[==] $x.polymod($_ xx*)}}
```

**Explained (sort of)**

For reference, a variable `$^x` in `{ ... }` is the same as doing `-> $x { ... }`

```perl6
{grep 2..$^x-2: {[==] $x.polymod($_ xx*)}}
{                                          # Anonymous function taking $x
 grep                                      # Return the all values in
      2..$^x-2: {                          # Range from 2 to $x - 2 satisfying:
                 [==]                      #     Reduce with ==:
                      $x.polymod(          #         (See below for polymod)
                                 $_ xx*    #         An infinite list containing
                                           #         the current value
                                       )}}
```

Polymod (TL;DR): `$n.polymod($b xx *)` gives you a reversed list of digits/'digits' for `$n` in base `$b`

Polymod (For real): The polymod method is almost like a more powerful version of python's `divmod` function. `$n.polymod(*@args)` divides $n by each value in *@args, adding the remainder (`$n mod $x`) to the list it returns, and using the quotient for the next division. I feel I explained it poorly so here's some examples (written in perl 6, but clean enough to be understood by most I hope):

```perl6
12.polymod(7)    # returns (5, 1)
# Roughly equivalent to:
(12 mod 7, 12 div 7)

86400.polymod(60,60,24) # returns (0, 0, 0, 1)
# Roughly equivalent to (this will give you an array rather than a list):
my $n = 86400;
my @remainders; # Here lies the end result
for (60, 60, 24) -> $divisor {
    @remainders.push( $n mod $divisor );
    $n div= $divisor;
}
@remainders.push($n)

# This is essentially the base conversion algorithm everyone
# knows and loves rolled into a method.
# Given an infinite list of divisors, polymod keeps going until
# the remainder given is 0.     
0xDEADBEEF.polymod(16 xx *) # returns (15 14 14 11 13 10 14 13)
# Roughly equivalent to (but gives an array rather than a list):
my $n = 0xDEADBEEF;
my @remainders; # Here lies the end result
while $n > 0 {
    @remainders.push( $n mod 16 );
    $n div= 16;
}
```

Comment: Actually since you are allowed to output "**any or all**" of the valid values, you can use the `grep` method instead of the `first` method.

Comment: Oh good catch, I missed that

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
3-:Q"G@:YAd~?@
```

This works with [current version (14.0.0)](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/14.0.0) of the language/compiler.

If no base exists, the output is empty (which is falsey).

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=My06USJHQDpZQWR-P0A&input=OTE)

```
3-:Q    % take input x implicitly. Generate range of possible bases: [2,3,...,x-2]
"       % for each base b
  G     %   push input again
  @:    %   generate vector of (1-based) digits in base b: [1,2,...,b]
  YA    %   convert to that base
  d~    %   differences between consecutive digits; negate
  ?     %   if all values are true (that is, if all digits were equal)
    @   %     push that base
        %   end if implicitly
        % end for each implicitly
        % display implicitly
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>26</s> 19 bytes

```
hMfql{eT1m,djQdr2tQ
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=hMfql%7BeT1m%2CdjQdr2tQ&input=91&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=11%0A23%0A55%0A90%0A91&debug=0)

<s>Will add an explanation after I golfed this.</s> Look at [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/75629/49110) for a shorter implementation and explanation.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that I forgot the additional bases for `90` and `91` in my examples!

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 55 bytes

```
Cases[4~Range~#-2,a_/;Equal@@#~IntegerDigits~a]/.{}->0&
```

Anonymous function, not too complicated. Just filters out bases based on repdigit-ness.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 75 bytes

```
n=input()
b=1
while b<n-2:
 i=n;b+=1
 while i%b==i/b%b:i/=b
 if i<b:print b
```

A port of my ruby answer. Prints all valid bases if any exists.

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 45 bytes

```
n->filter(b->endof(∪(digits(n,b)))<2,2:n-2)
```

This is an anonymous function that accepts an integer and returns an integer array. To call it, assign it to a variable. It will return all applicable bases or an empty array. There are no issues with large bases.

First we generate the inclusive range [2, *n* - 2], where *n* is the input. We then `filter` the list to only integers *b* for which *n* in base *b* has fewer than 2 unique digits. To do this, for each integer *b* in the range, we get the digits of *n* in base *b* as an array using `digits`, get unique items using `∪`, and get the index of the last element (i.e. the length) using `endof`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 12 bytes

```
>>.ℕ₂≜&ḃ↙.=∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVwAo/9icmFjaHlsb2cy/3t3IiAtLT4gInc/e@KGsOKCg3ziiKciZmFsc2UuIn3huol94bWQ/z4@LuKEleKCguKJnCbhuIPihpkuPeKIp///WzExLDIzLDU1LDkwLDkxXQ) [(as a generator!)](https://tio.run/##AVEArv9icmFjaHlsb2cy/3t3IiAtLT4gInc/4oaw4oKC4bag4bqJfeG1kP8@Pi7ihJXigoLiiZwm4biD4oaZLj3iiKf//1sxMSwyMyw1NSw5MCw5MV0)

Takes input through the input variable and outputs a base through the output variable in the case that this is possible, failing otherwise. At the same time, it also works as a [generator](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10753/85334) which outputs a list of all bases, where that list can be empty.

Ideally this could look something like `ḃ↙.=&>>`, possibly sacrificing generator functionality in that form or a similar one (since it would eventually hit unary), but as of now 12 bytes is the shortest I know how to get it.

```
     ≜          Assign an integer value to
  .             the output variable
   ℕ₂           which is greater than or equal to 2
 >              and less than a number
>               which is less than the input.
      &         The input
       ḃ↙.      in base-(the output)
          =     is a repdigit.
           ∧    (which is not necessarily the output)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>46</s> 43 bytes

Uses the [Integer#digits](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-digits) function introduced in Ruby 2.4 to avoid needing to manually divide.

-3 bytes thanks to @Jordan.

```ruby
->n{(2..n-2).find{|i|!n.digits(i).uniq[1]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWsNITy9P10hTLy0zL6W6JrNGMU8vJTM9s6RYI1NTrzQvszDaMLa29n@BQlq0SrxeSX58Zmx5RmZOqkJ6aknxf0NDLiNjLlNTLksDLktDAA)

Comment: @Jordan ah yes I keep forgetting that trick haha

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÍL¦ʒвÙg
```

Outputs all possible values, or an empty list as falsey value (although technically valid outputs are falsey as well, since only `1` is truthy in 05AB1E, and everything else is falsey).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cK/PoWWnJl3YdHhm@v//lgYA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##ATgAx/9vc2FiaWX/dnnDkFU/IiDihpIgIj//w41MwqbKklhz0LLDmWf/fSz/WzExLDIzLDU1LDkwLDkxXQ).

**Explanation:**

```python
Í        # Decrease the (implicit) input-integer by 2
 L       # Create a list in the range [1, input-2]
  ¦      # Remove the first value to make the range [2, input-2]
   ʒ     # Filter this list by:
    в    #  Convert the (implicit) input to the base of the number we're filtering
     Ù   #  Uniquify it, leaving only distinct digits
      g  #  Get the length of this, which is truthy (1) if all digits were the same
         # (and then output the filtered list implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-Minteger -na`, 63 bytes

```perl
map{$r=$,=($c="@F")%$_;$r*=$c%$_==$,while$c/=$_;$r&&say}2..$_-2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83saBapchWRcdWQyXZVsnBTUlTVSXeWqVIy1YlGciyBUqVZ2TmpKok69uCJdTUihMra4309FTidY3@/7c0AMJ/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwNgHRmXklqemrRf928RAA)

Outputs all possible answers or nothing if no solution exists.